# Read a txt file in Mathematica

Tags: file, wolfram-mathematica, readfile

Does anyone know how to read a .txt file from Mathematica in lines and save those lines as elements from an array? The file I'm trying to read are names like this:

- Brad Pitt
- Scarlet Johanson
- Woody Allen
- etc

I have no experience with Mathematica by the way, thanks.

Comment: Search Mathematica's generally good documentation for the `Import` function.

Comment: Thanks I just checked the answers and review the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows and your text file is named `C:\dir\names.txt`, then you can use

```
names = StringSplit[Import["C:/dir/names.txt"], "\n"]
```

to import the file, and then split the resulting string at the end of each new line into an array of strings. Note the different direction of the slashes.

If you aren't on Windows, the command is the same, but the directory won't be prefixed with a drive letter.

Comment: Thanks I just tried and it works, I'm working on iOS

Answer (score 2):

`ReadList["filename.txt", String]` is the command that reads a file called `filename.txt` and puts each line, as a string, into a List (which is an array).